# Como posso passar dados entre classe python

Tags: python

Eu tenho duas classe, uma para a mainWindow e a outra para um QDialog:

```
class Menu(QMainWindow):
  logginuser= None
  def __init__(self,):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
```

A class Entrega que é do QDialog é chamada através de um botão que se conecta a esta função:

```
def switch_windows(self):

    self.entrega2 = Entrega(self.tableLinhaNova)
```

E a classe Entrega é a seguinte:

```
class Entrega(QDialog):
def __init__(self, source_table_widget,parent=Menu):

    QDialog.__init__(self)
    self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

Mas na classe Entrega tem uma informação que eu quero passar para a classe Menu que é esta:

```
    self.projeto=self.ui.comboBoxProjeto.currentIndex()
    self.idproj = self.ui.comboBoxProjeto.itemData(self.projeto)
```

self.idproj é um Id, pode ser 1,2,3 etc...

Como posso passar o self.idproj para a classe Menu

Comment: Já tentou criar um parâmetro no construtor da classe que irá receber esse valor?

Comment: @Woss Na classe Menu certo?

Comment: Se é para ela que precisa mandar o valor, sim

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá, me parece um problema de O.O. Segue um exemplo:

```
class Carro:

def __init__(self,cor,ano,motor):
    self.cor = cor
    self.ano = ano
    self.motor = motor

def print_dados(self):
    print(f'O carro é {self.cor} e o ano é {self.ano}')

class Motor:
def __init__(self,nome,potencia):
    self.nome = nome
    self.potencia = potencia
    
def check_pot(self):
    return f'A potência é : {self.potencia}'
```

Se observar, passo o objeto motor no construtor da classe Carro, daí consigo acessar a informação desejada da classe motor através do carro, porque o carro contém o motor.

```
motor = Motor('v8',300)
carro = Carro('Vermelho',2000 ,motor)

print(f'A potencia do motor do carro {carro.cor} é {carro.motor.check_pot()}')
```

Até...

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).